# The method setArray(int, Array) in the type PreparedStatement is not applicable for the arguments (String, String[])

Tags: java, arrays, spring-data

> Guys i am new to java i am getting this error please help me out
>   what i am trying to do is get result in array

```
        public List<DeviceDetail> list(String[] deviceIds) throws Exception {
        List<DeviceDetail> appList = new ArrayList<>(); 
        Connection conn =null;
        CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("{call 
        Application_List(?)}");
        statement.setArray("Deviceid",deviceIds);
        boolean isResultSet = statement.execute();
        if (isResultSet) {
            try (ResultSet rs = statement.getResultSet()) {
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        DeviceDetail dd = new DeviceDetail();
                        dd.setDeviceId(rs.getString("DeviceId"));
                        dd.setToken(rs.getString("Token"));
                        dd.setDeviceType(rs.getString("DeviceType"));
                        dd.setCreatedBy(rs.getString("CreatedBy"));
                        dd.setCreatedTime(rs.getTimestamp("CreatedTime"));
                        dd.setStatus(rs.getBoolean("Status"));
                        appList.add(dd);
                    }
                }
            }
        return appList;
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setArray-int-java.sql.Array- and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Array.html are you sure you need that? What does `Application_List` looks like?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
statement.setArray(1, array);
```

You need to specify wildcard location as `Integer` not `String`.

**Edit**

Create `java.sql.Array` using below method.

```
Array array = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", deviceIds);
```

Comment: sorry for that. I just edited the answer. have a look.

Comment: its ok thanks for the help 
you mean by that ...?
public List<DeviceDetail> list(String[] deviceIds) throws Exception {List<DeviceDetail> appList = new ArrayList<>(); 
Connection conn =null;
conn = dataSource.getConnection();
Array array = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", deviceIds);
CallableStatement statement = conn.prepareCall("{call DeviceDetail_List(?)}");
statement.setArray(2,array);

Comment: `statement.setArray(1, array);` here 1 is index of parameter to be passed.